# Ann didn’t have enough money but she would buy this dress anyway

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> Ann didn’t have enough money but she would buy this dress anyway.

in that sentence **would** is like **past of "will"**?

another question

> My mother would always make the pies. Active
>
> The pies would always be made by my mother. Passive

this **passive** is past tense?

Comment: Hi VIkea Mahun, welcome to EL&U StackExchange! This particular question is trivial for native speakers and such questions are usually off-topic on this site; please consider the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) Stack Exchange instead.  In addition, EL&U has a 'research requirement': you are supposed to have attempted to answer the question yourself using commonly available resources and are supposed to summarize this research, explaining why you still don't think you know the answer. The ELL SE also has a research requirement, but it is arguably less strict.